# Expand widget to parent item in listview

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Stumbled across a problem while trying to make a layout.

Base idea. I have a listview with following items

`|
o   Header
|   TextA
|   TextBCD
|   Some other multiline, variable height text text
|`

where the lines and `o` sign are some kind of a `pathway` from top to bottom. they should connect one listitem to another.

the `texts` and header can have different texts. 1-2-3 lines. Variable height.

The problem:
- how to make pathway to `match_parent` to `texts` frame? So far I cannot stretch/expand `pathway` because it will give error/make infinite height list item.

Any ideas?

Code link:
https://pastebin.com/dRhSmWJy

[image: More visual question]

Comment: I didn't get you clearly, how much I got, have you tried Expanded widget

Comment: If possible, Please add your code

Comment: put some code, for better understanding. it is not clear.

Comment: added code. Cannot expand bottom line to fill parent heigth. Only can constraint is with fixed height, that will either expand parent widget or won't tie to bottom